# No matching function for call to operator new

Tags: c++, new-operator

I'm trying to wrap a class from a library I'm using in Lua. Specifially, I'm trying to wrap the color class from SFML. The full source for the color class can be seen [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6/Color_8cpp-source.htm) and [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6/Color_8hpp-source.htm).

This is the function that's that I'm failing in.

```
int SFColor_new(lua_State* L)
{
    // omitting part where I set r, g, b, and a
    new (lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(Color))) Color(r, g, b, a); // Line 47
    luaL_getmetatable(L, LuaInfo<Color>::myMetaTableName);
    lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
    return 1;
}
```

And this is the error

```
LuaSFMLColor.cpp: In function ‘int ag::SFColor_new(lua_State*)’:
LuaSFMLColor.cpp:47: error: no matching function for call to ‘operator new(unsigned int, void*)’
<built-in>:0: note: candidates are: void* operator new(unsigned int)
make: *** [game] Error 1
```

I do similar things in a few other places without running into this error, so I'm not sure what would be causing it. Looking at the Color's source code I don't see anything weird or out of the ordinary, and I've run out of ideas. I've also tried using the default constructor (i.e. no arguments) and then just setting the value afterward, but that didn't do any good either.

Comment: I didn't know that at the time. :P

Answer (score 116, accepted):

To use the standard placement form of `new` you have to `#include <new>`.

The form of `new` that you are using requires a declaration of `void* operator new(std::size_t, void*) throw();`.

You don't have to `#include <new>` to use non-placement `new`.

Comment: +1. I never knew that. Perhaps a lot of STL headers use placement new (for rather obvious reasons) and I never had to #include it manually myself, but if you had a file where you didn't have, say, vector, then you might need to manually include it.

Comment: This did it. I never realized it either until this was posted. It must be buried in some of the other headers I've been using without me ever knowing. Thanks. :) You learn something new everyday. (pun intended)

Comment: I recently allowed `clang-format` to sort my includes and this error popped up, because the system includes used to be first. Thanks for the knowledge.

Comment: An enhancement request was added [to Clang](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=49260) and [to GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=99158), to provide a better error message when using `placement new` and missing `#include <new>`. Something like: _Note: use of placement new requires #include <new>_.

Answer (score 1):

The question has already been answered, but here's possible solution if you did `#include <new>` and still get `error: no matching 'operator new' function for non-allocating placement new expression; include <new>` **on clang**.
My code looked like this:

```cpp
int* fun(const std::array<std::byte, 123>& param, std::size_t offset) {
    return new(param.data()+offset) int;
}
```

When I switched to GCC, I got `error: invalid conversion from 'const void*' to 'void*`, which is significantly more useful. `param` must be passed by non-const reference.
It might seem obvious, but the original code was much more complex and it was difficult to spot the actual source of the issue.