# 'operator new' : function does not take 2 arguments

Tags: c++, placement-new

I cannot seem to get my placement new to work for some reason. Based on this question, I have set this up [correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new).

However, I continue to get the error:

> 'operator new' : function does not take 2 arguments

Here is my code:

```
char * p = new char [sizeof(Node) * 5];
Node* node = new(p) Node();
```

where `Node` is a linked list node. I have tried to simplify this down based on the other stack overflow question, and I am still getting the same error:

```
char *buf  = new char[sizeof(int)]; // pre-allocated buffer
int *p = new (buf) int;
```

Does anyone know why I am having this issue?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

PS, this works:

```
Node* node = new Node();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [No matching function for call to operator new](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156778/no-matching-function-for-call-to-operator-new)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Most likely, you didn't include `<new>`. You need that for the declarations of the standard forms of placement-new.

Comment: Wow the little things you can miss! Thank you!

Comment: @Mike Seymour - +1 for the great answer. A question regarding a case I'm facing: I'm using Microsoft C/C++ compiler version 19.13.26128 (for x86), and in my case, in order to eliminate the error in the question, I needed to use add the global scope before the new keyword. So utilizing one of the examples from the code of the question, I wrote: Node* node = ::new (p) Node(); - Do you have an idea why it is like this ? (also note that the compiler does not asks me to include the <new> header file). Thanks !!

Comment: It might be worth to mention that another case where this would happen is if you are constructing a class via placement-new that has a **custom new operator**. Cost me a good amount of time trying to include <new> everywhere when I had this problem.